# Access a record field

Tags: opa

This code source don't compile, Is there a way to make that in OPA ?

```
type User = { nom : string ; prenom : string }
un_user = { nom = "My_name" ; prenom = "My_last_name" } : User
champ = "nom"
do jlog(un_user.`champ`)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Runtime magic is possible in Opa, using the OpaValue module which contains feature for runtime introspection of values (not type safe)

http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#opavalue.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.OpaValue.Record

But this is not for casual user, and a very dangerous coding style.
It is often a need coming from code written in a coding style corresponding to scripts and runtime evaluated language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do... if to print the nom field of `un_user` then you can do:

```
do jlog(un_user.nom)
```

if you really want to access record field with a dynamic name, then this cannot be done in Opa (AFAIK).